# Display Camera Image in VS PictureBox W/0 Saving To PC Drive

Tags: vb.net

If I save (to disk) the image transferred from the camera, I can display it in a PictureBox, as follows:

```
Dim picNum As Integer = 1
Dim imgName As String
Dim imgExt As String
Dim WiaDialog1 As New WIA.CommonDialog
Dim WiaDevice1 As WIA.Device = WiaDialog1.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.CameraDeviceType, False, False)
imgName = WiaDevice1.Items(picNum).Properties("Item Name").Value
imgExt = "." & WiaDevice1.Items(picNum).Properties("Filename extension").Value
Dim image1 As WIA.ImageFile = WiaDevice1.Items(picNum).Transfer(WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatPNG)
image1.SaveFile("C:\PhotoSort\CameraNew2\" & imgName & imgExt)
image1 = "C:\PhotoSort\CameraNew2\" & imgName & imgExt"  
PictureBox1.Image = image1
```

I want to display the transferred image, in a similar VB code manner,. without saving it to disk

Answer (score 0):

You can display image from physical location like

```
Picturebox1.Image=Image.FromFile("Path");
```

Comment: Thank you.  Would that physical location perhaps be directed back to the camera , as in FromFile(filename in camera's DCIM folder?)  Or at  least, somewhere not on disk.